# URL Rewrite for Forwarding Proxy for HTTPS

Tags: https, proxy

Is it possible to create **forwarding** HTTPS Proxy (not reverse proxy) that would be able to:

- block some urls based on the url regexp (ads, flash, movies, ...)
- cache images based on the url regexp

It seems to me that in the usual case it is impossible because the HTTPS stream is encrypted and there's no way to process or alter it.

But, **this case is special**, it is a proxy for the web crawler, I don't need HTTPS at all, but some sites allow access via HTTPS only, and I have to somehow support it.

So, maybe it would be possible to do something like that?

`Crawler --http--> Proxy --https--> Site`

So, the proxy would be able to decode HTTPS stream and post-process it. Would it work? Is there any docs or details about such approach?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure Apache 2.2 provides this functionality with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) in conjunction with mod_ssl and mod_cache.

Note: blocking is done using the 'ProxyBlock' directive in mod_proxy.